# Logout User NodeJS, ExpressJS, SQLite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, jwt

I am creating a website where the user is able to sign up, login and logout.
I have managed to make the signup and login work, however, I am stuck on the logout.

When the user logs in, there is a jsonwebtoken that gets generated for that user, however, I would like to show the logout button when they log in and hide the sign in button. At the moment, I have been able to hide the logout button via CSS.

Also, I am not sure if the token is actually attached to the user and the logout not working.

Below is my code:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');


const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const PORT = 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('images'));

const db = new sqlite3.Database('database.db');

// Create a table for storing user data if it doesn't exist
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    firstName TEXT,
    surname TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    password TEXT
)`);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"message":"Ok"});
});

// GET All Users
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    // Retrieve all users from the database
    db.all('SELECT * FROM users', (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error retrieving users:', err.message);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving users' });
        } else {
            // Send the user data as a JSON response
            res.status(200).json(rows);
        }
    });
});

// Register a User
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, surname, email, password } = req.body;

    // Insert the user data into the database
    db.run('INSERT INTO users (firstName, surname, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
        [firstName, surname, email, password],
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error inserting user:', err.message);
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error registering user' });
            } else {
                console.log(`User with id ${this.lastID} registered successfully`);
                res.status(200).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
            }
        }
    );
});

// Login a User
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Check if the user with the provided email and password exists in the database
    db.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', [email, password], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error during login:', err.message);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error during login' });
        } else if (row) {
            // User found, generate a JWT
            // Set expiration time for the token - 1hr 
            const token = jwt.sign({ userId: row.id, email: row.email }, 'your-secret-key', { expiresIn: '1h' }); 

            // User found, send a success response with user data
            res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful', user: row, token });
            console.log('Login successful', row);
        } else {
            // User not found or invalid credentials
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid email or password' });
            console.log('Invalid email or password');
        }
    });
});


app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.query;

    // Check if the user with the provided email and password exists in the database
    db.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', [email, password], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error during login:', err.message);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error during login' });
        } else if (row) {
            // User found, send a success response
            res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful' });
        } else {
            // User not found or invalid credentials
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid email or password' });
        }
    });
});

// Logout User
app.get('/logout',(req,res) => {
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('/')
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

signInScript.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const emailInput = document.getElementById('signInEmailAddress');
    const passwordInput = document.getElementById('signInPassword');
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    const togglePasswordIcon = document.getElementById('togglePassword');
  
    // Function to check if email and password fields are filled and enable/disable the submit button
    function checkFormValidity() {
        const isValid = emailInput.value.trim() !== '' && passwordInput.value.trim() !== '';
        submitButton.disabled = !isValid;
    }
  
    // Function to handle password visibility toggle
    function togglePasswordVisibility() {
        const type = passwordInput.type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
        passwordInput.type = type;
        togglePasswordIcon.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
    }
  
    // Event listeners for input fields
    emailInput.addEventListener('input', checkFormValidity);
    passwordInput.addEventListener('input', checkFormValidity);
  
    // Event listener for password visibility toggle
    togglePasswordIcon.addEventListener('click', togglePasswordVisibility);
  
    // Prevent form submission for demonstration purposes
    document.getElementById("signInForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const email = document.getElementById("signInEmailAddress").value;
        const password = document.getElementById("signInPassword").value;
    
        // Prepare data to be sent to the server
        const data = {
            email: email,
            password: password
        };
    
        // Send data to the server using fetch API
        fetch('/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                // Login successful
                return response.json(); // Parse the JSON response
            } else {
                // Login failed
                console.error('Login failed');
                // Show an error message to the user
                alert("Login Failed!");
                throw new Error('Login failed');
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            // Access user data from the response
            console.log('User data:', data.user);
            // Redirect to another page or perform other actions with the user data
            alert("Login Successful!");

            console.log(data.token);

            // Store the token in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            // Handle errors here
        });
    });
});
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using token based authentication, not any session, so you can remove session piece of code.

When you return the jwt token in login, save it and send it in each api call, and verify on each call, thats how token auth works.

And after a token has been generated, you can not manually expire. You can not log out on the server side with JWT. so removing jwt from frontend so it cant be attached to any request is the way to handle the logout.